# Page style takes time to load with Next Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, frontend, next.js

The style of the page takes time to load when the user open the page or make reload in the page. I don't have much time working with next js, still learning the hard skills of the framework.

This is an gif showing when i open the page. This also happens when I reload or enter a page and come back right away: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0k0mS.jpg

This is my `_document.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import Document, { Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
import { ServerStyleSheet } from 'styled-components';

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  static getInitialProps({ renderPage }) {
    const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
    const page = renderPage(App => props => sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />));
    const styleTags = sheet.getStyleElement();

    return { ...page, styleTags };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <html lang="en">
        <Head>
          {this.props.styleTags}

          <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.webmanifest" />
          <meta name="them-color" content="#189AB4" />
          <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/next/icons/icon-72x72.png" />
        </Head>

        <body>
          <Main />
          <div id="portal" />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </html>
    );
  }
}
```

and this is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "novo-site",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@zeit/next-css": "^1.0.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "classnames": "2.2.6",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "formik": "2.1.5",
    "jquery": "3.5.1",
    "lodash": "4.17.20",
    "next": "11.0.0",
    "next-absolute-url": "^1.2.2",
    "next-compose-plugins": "^2.2.1",
    "next-images": "^1.8.1",
    "next-transpile-modules": "^8.0.0",
    "normalize.css": "8.0.1",
    "polished": "3.6.5",
    "prop-types": "15.7.2",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-animated-burgers": "1.2.8",
    "react-collapse": "5.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-is": "16.13.1",
    "react-on-screen": "2.1.1",
    "react-reveal": "1.2.2",
    "react-scroll": "1.8.1",
    "react-slick": "0.27.9",
    "react-sticky-el": "2.0.5",
    "react-string-replace": "0.4.4",
    "react-use": "15.3.3",
    "shortid": "2.2.15",
    "slick-carousel": "1.8.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.0",
    "styled-media-query": "2.1.2",
    "styled-system": "5.1.5",
    "typewriter-effect": "^2.18.0",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.39.1",
    "yup": "0.29.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "17.0.11",
    "typescript": "4.3.2",
    "webpack": "^5.23.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution after try fix other bug on the project. Basically, my project has two custom pages, `_app.jsx` and `_document.jsx`, but outside the `/pages` directory.
After read the documentation, could see this difference with the docs recomendation. Then i moved `_app.jsx` and `_document.jsx` to `/pages` folder and got the right solution.